# How auto scale the x-axis of a plot using VBA?

Tags: excel, axis, vba

I'm trying to autoscale a plot in Excel, unfortunately, I only managed to scale the Y axis, because I get an error while setting the Maximum value of the X axis :

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Method 'MaximumScale' of object 'Axis' failed

I have got this code to help me scale my plot :

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoScaleAxe()

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("E26").Value
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("E25").Value
        .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("E27").Value
    End With

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        'The following line raises an error
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("E22").Value
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("E21").Value
        .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("E23").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Here are the cells I use to scale the plot :

[image: Cells used to scale the plot]

Comment: What kind of chart is it?

Comment: I get the same error if I try your code on a line chart, but it works OK on a scatter chart. I suspect your chart type doesn't have a `MaximumScale` property.

Comment: My aim is to display a normal distribution, therefore I chose to use an histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly if the chart type has a numeric horizontal axis - e.g. a scatter chart - but not if the horizontal axis is categorical.

If you want to display a histogram using a categorical type like a column chart, you'll need to either:

1. set up the chart with a fixed number of data points (i.e. fixed number of bins) and recalculate the actual data points (bin values) as the desired axis min and max are altered, or
2. calculate data points spanning the largest range of axis min to max that you want to cover, and alter the chart series data source range, e.g. `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = myrange`.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/) post explains, you can't use MinimumScale, MaximumScale of a chart with categorical X-axis.

The only thing that's available is TickLabelSpacing and TickMarkSpacing. Or, as @nekomatic explains, you should use numeric X-axis.